# Treeview blank display C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, treeview, nodes

I am attempting to fill a Treeview using an array filled with instances of a class I created. There are no errors, but nothing appears in the view. Here is the code I am using to fill the Tree. It is placed in the form Constructer.

```
        for (int index = 0; index < jobArray.Length - 1; index++)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
            newNode.Text = jobArray[index].name;
            newNode.Tag = jobArray[index].trusses;
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);

        }
```

Any Suggestions? thanks!

Comment: What you have should work, have you tried putting a breakpoint on your for loop and check to make sure that jobArray actually has data? Also if you show us your complete constructor it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the condition in the loop (-1) it should work fine:

```
for (int index = 0; index < jobArray.Length; index++)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
            newNode.Text = jobArray[index].name;
            newNode.Tag = jobArray[index].trusses;
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);

        }
```